# Volley sends If-Modified-Since when the document does not have Last-Modified

Tags: android-volley

I'm using Android Volley Networking library in a project.

When I add "if-None-Match" with etag to the header myself I am not getting 304 because Volley also adds "If-Modified-Since". The cached response did not have "Last-Modified" in the header.

Should Volley send "If-Modified-Since", if the cached request did not have "Last-Modified"?

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr:** no, I don't believe Volley should be sending `If-Modified-Since` as part of its requests, at least not the way it is currently doing it.

**Longer answer:**

Volley is setting the `If-Modified-Since` header using the `Date` header from the previous response [here](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/abc9b484b421b47418f53d5487fec43f140431af/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpHeaderParser.java#L53-L56) and [here](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/abc9b484b421b47418f53d5487fec43f140431af/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java#L230-L233).

Looks like there's a [patch here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/108480/) to fix volley so that it behaves more appropriately (i.e., uses the `Last-Modified` response header).

Here's two subsequent requests that both yield 200 responses from Volley/Android:

```
Request 1
If-None-Match: "cd090c6cb990a25585f1748d85d764bd"
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 16 Dec 2014 14:21:13 GMT+00:00

Response 1
ETag: "cd090c6cb990a25585f1748d85d764bd"
Date: Tue, 16 Dec 2014 14:21:29 GMT

Request 2
If-None-Match: "cd090c6cb990a25585f1748d85d764bd"
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 16 Dec 2014 14:21:29 GMT+00:00

Response 2
ETag: "cd090c6cb990a25585f1748d85d764bd"
Date: Tue, 16 Dec 2014 14:23:31 GMT
```

The responses don't include the `Last-Modified` header so http clients don't have an appropriate value for `If-Modified-Since`... yet Volley sends `If-Modified-Since` with the Date value from the previous response.